# Is it possible to only use the "C++ Extensions for Networking" interfaces implemented in Asio, to make a simple synchronous application?

Tags: network-programming, boost-asio, std, c++20

I am trying to implement a simple client and server using standalone Asio (non-boost). I saw on this page (in the ducumentation):

http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/net_ts.html

that Asio is currently implementing the interface for networking that will be supported in the C++20 standard. I would like to use that interface for my application so that when the new standard libraries will be available, I will have just to change the headers and still have working application. So my question are:

1) Do you think is possible to use Asio with only the interfaces reported on the page?

2) If yes, could you show me simple code samples to do DNS resolution, connect (client), accept (server) and read/write operations (no asychronous stuff, only blocking)? Please indicate also the namespaces you used.

As a reference for the operations I want to perform (look under section echo and the non blocking client and server):
http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html

Comment: "*the interface for networking that will be supported in the C++20 standard*" There is no networking in C++20. It was delayed for various reasons.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I read some outdated information. I'll try anyway to use the interfaces that are specified on the Asio site and in the proposal: https://cplusplus.github.io/networking-ts/draft.pdf and post the solution if I manage to do that (I saw it is a matter of not using some of the asio typedefs).

Comment: I think that in the page http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/net_ts.html are reported only the interfaces they (partially) deprecated since different from what indicated in the standard proposal. So I think no matter how you use the asio network functionalities (as long as not deprecated) they should be compliant with the proposed standard (but I'm not sure 100%)